# Chess - algorithm, designate jumps

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

I have a question.

We have unlimited board, How to measure the amount of a half where you may find yourself jumper after n jumps?

For example:

after one jump we have 8 boxes

after two jump we have 33 boxes

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int sign(int n)
{
  if(n > 0 )return 1;
  else if(n == 0) return 0;
  else return -1;
}


int main()
{
  int t, n;
  cin >> t;
  for(int i = 0; i < t; i++)
  {
    cin >> n;
    cout << 7*n*n + 4*n - 3*sign(n-2)*sign(n-1) << endl;

  }
}


//f(n) = 7*n^2 + 4*n - 3*Sign[(n - 2)(n - 1)]
```

What's wrong?

My code return 11, for n = 1, should return 8

ok, working!

Comment: you are jumping with what?   `the amount of a half` what is this? `after one jump we have 8 boxes` you mean we cover 8 cells? what kind of jump we are allowed to do?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight_%28chess%29

Comment: you mean to say that after 1 jump we may find yourself in 8 different cells, after 2  - 33

Comment: What's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By writing a simple python program:

```
dx = [-2, -2, -1, -1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
dy = [-1, 1, -2, 2, -2, 2, -1, 1]

def calc(level):
    cell_list = set([(0,0)])
    for _ in range(level):
        new_cell_list = set()
        for x, y in cell_list:
            for k in range(len(dx)):
                new_cell_list.add((x+dx[k], y+dy[k]))
        cell_list = new_cell_list

    return len(cell_list)


for level in range(1, 10):
    print(calc(level), end=', ')
```

we get

```
8, 33, 76, 129, 196, 277, 372, 481, 604
```

which is [A118312](https://oeis.org/search?q=8%2C%2033%2C%2076%2C%20129%2C%20196%2C%20277%2C%20372%2C%20481%2C%20604&language=english&go=Search). The formula is:

```
f(n) = 7*n^2 + 4*n - 3 + 4*Sign[(n - 2)(n - 1)]
```

where

```
           1   n > 0
Sign(n) =  0   n == 0
          -1   n < 0
```

This is the same as:

```
f(0) = 1
f(1) = 8
f(2) = 33
f(n) = 7*n^2 + 4*n + 1, n >= 3
```